# Call button in navigationbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Have a `NSMutableArray` with sorting by a distance. So I need a call button or label in `UINavigationBar` (right button) with call function using dictionary and valueKey. How can I realize it?

Here is code that I'm using:

```
- (void)updateViewWithDict:(NSDictionary*)dic {
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nAddress: %@\nPhone: %@\n\nWorkTime:\n%@", [dic valueForKey:@"name"], [dic valueForKey:@"address"], [dic valueForKey:@"phone"], [dic valueForKey:@"workTime"]];

    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 110, 300, 140)];
    nameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    nameLabel.text = str;
    nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0];

    UIBarButtonItem *callButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Call"
                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil]; 

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = callButton;
}
```

I can't get how to assign `NSURL` to my button?

I tried to use code like this.. but what next?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",[dic valueForKey:@"phone"]]]];
```

===

Solution:- I found the way like this:

in `- (void)updateViewWithDict:(NSDictionary*)dic` I wrote if statement

```
if ([[dic valueForKey:@"phone"]  isEqual: @"12345"]){

        UIBarButtonItem *callButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Call" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(FirstOffice:)];

       self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = callButton;

    }

    else if ([[dic valueForKey:@"phone"]  isEqual: @"67890]){

        UIBarButtonItem *callButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Call" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(SecondOffice:)];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = callButton2;
    }
```

and methods like this

```
- (void)FirstOffice:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://12345"]]];
}

- (void)SecondOffice:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://67890"]]];
}
```

Maybe there is another way? more easier way?) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the `target` and `action` parameters in `initWithTitle:style:target:action:` are used for the on-click action:

```
UIBarButtonItem *callButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Call" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(buttonTapped)];
```

Then define the method:

```
-(void)buttonTapped
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",[dic valueForKey:@"phone"]]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this

```
UIBarButtonItem *callButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Call"
                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(callSomeone:);
```

and add the method

```
- (void)callSomeone:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",[dic objectForKey:@"phone"]]]];
}
```

Comment: i tried something like this, but in void method [dic valueForKey...] doesn't recognizing...

Comment: `-objectForKey:` in when interacting with dictionaries.